# Extracting string from a txt file

Tags: .net, regex, string, extract

I have a txt file that contains some values that I would like to extract: like the number after `"YOUR NUMBER:"`

`"YOUR NUMBER:"` has no space, made by a first group of 3digits "-" and #digits

```
---***---
i.e.:
[some text here]

YOUR NUMBER:
123-12345678

[some other text here]
---***---
```

I started to look at `RegEx`, but to be honest, I am poor in coding skill, so I am asking for help.
I need to extract and save it in excel, SQL, or similar.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

RegEx: YOUR NUMBER:\n.*?\n
You can try RegExs at http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non regex apporach:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string line = lines[i];
    if (line.Trim().Equals("YOUR NUMBER:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        string number = lines[i + 1].Trim();
        string[] bothNums = number.Split('-');
        if (bothNums.Length == 2 && bothNums[0].Length == 3 && bothNums.All(n => n.All(Char.IsDigit)))
            numbers.Add(number);
    }
}
```